# Highstock: xy zooming with panning

Tags: highcharts

How can I get x y zooming and also panning?

Ideally it would be possible to select a rectangle with the mouse (xy zooming) which I already have and also to  pan after zoom has been made, for that maybe something like pressing a key while dragging would work for zooming.

But I don't have idea how to implement this. Haven't found a solution for this.

Comment: In the highcharts you can define a panning and panKey to run that behaviour on desktop. See option http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.panKey and let me know if that is answer for you questions.

Comment: Thanks, but that option doesnt seem to be available for highstock

Comment: For me this working fine, also in highstock. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ln43k8kz/2/. As I see in the docs this param is missing, but exists.

Comment: @SebastianBochan Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the highcharts you can define a panning and panKey to run that behaviour on desktop. See option http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.panKey

```
chart: {
    panKey: 'shift'
}
```